# How to calculate the size of video ？

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with Xamarin.iOS. I use UIImagePickerController to record video . Now I get the filePath of the video in sandBox . But I want to calculate the size of the video before I upload(over 20M will be banned) . I'm not familiar with native iOS(OC and Swift).I can only get the duration. So , how to get the size(in MB) of the video?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Class `NSFileManager` .Try to refer to the following code:

```
 public double GetFileSize(NSString filepath)
    {
        NSFileManager fileManager = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
        double filesize = -1.0;
        if (fileManager.FileExists(filepath))
        {
            filesize = (double)fileManager.GetAttributes(filepath).Size;
            return filesize / (1024 * 1024);  // return the size as MB
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("file can not be found");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```